# Получить список контактов почты imap/smtp c#

Tags: c#, smtp, imap

Добрый день, не подскажите, как можно получить список контактов в почте через imap/smtp. Насколько я понял, pop3 для этого не подходит. Язык c#, мб какие подходящие компоненты посоветуете